# Compare the structure table in two different databases and return difference

Tags: mysql

I need to compare tables in two databases and find the difference in column_name, data_type, is_nullable, column_default.   I want my output to be

```
db1.table
id   | int   | NOT_NULL | AUTO_INCREMEMT
name | text  | NOT_NULL |
YYYY | text  | NOT_NULL | 
ZZZZ | text  | NOT_NULL | 

db2.table
id   | int   | NOT_NULL | AUTO_INCREMEMT
name | text  | NOT_NULL |
YYYY | text  |          |
```

Query result I want

```
COLUMN_NAME | DATA_TYPE | IS_NULLABLE | COLUMN_DEFAULT
------------|-----------|-------------|---------------
YYYY        | TEXT      | NOT_NULL    |
YYYY        | TEXT      |             |
ZZZZ        | TEXT      | NOT_NULL    |
```

What I have so far.

```
(SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, IS_NULLABLE, COLUMN_DEFAULT
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE table_name = 'table_1' AND table_schema = 'db1')
UNION
(SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, IS_NULLABLE, COLUMN_DEFAULT
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE table_name = 'table_1' AND table_schema = 'db2')
```

Query results I get

```
COLUMN_NAME | DATA_TYPE | IS_NULLABLE    | COLUMN_DEFAULT
------------|-----------|----------------|---------------
id          | INT       | NOT_NULL       | AUTO_INCREMEMT
name        | TEXT      | NOT_NULL       |               
YYYY        | TEXT      | NOT_NULL       |               
YYYY        | TEXT      |                |
```

This gets close but returns too many rows and only show columns in both tables.  For example it does not show column ZZZZ but it does return column YYYY twice as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Problem**

It is very easy to come up with a solution if the problem is narrowed down to a single sentence, such as; *I would like to retrieve the unique set of partial rows from `<some table>`, where a pair of columns is either `<some pair>` or `<some other pair>`*.

---

With the previous sentence in mind we can quickly see that we need;

- A way to select which rows we would like to retrieve (`WHERE` + `IN`)
- A way to group directly equivalent rows together (`GROUP BY`)
- A way to filter out rows that show up only once (`HAVING` + `COUNT`)

---

---

**The Solution**

```
SELECT
  table_schema, table_name, column_name, data_type, is_nullable, column_default
FROM
  information_schema.columns
WHERE 
  (table_schema,table_name) IN (('db1','table_1'), ('db2','table_1'))
GROUP BY
  column_name, data_type, is_nullable, column_default
HAVING
  COUNT(*) = 1
```

<sub>**Result**</sub>

```
+--------------+------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------------+
| table_schema | table_name | column_name | data_type | is_nullable | column_default |
+--------------+------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------------+
| db1          | table_1    | YYYY        | text      | NO          | NULL           |
| db2          | table_1    | YYYY        | text      | YES         | NULL           |
| db1          | table_1    | ZZZZ        | text      | NO          | NULL           |
+--------------+------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------------+
```

---

---

**Preparations**

```
CREATE DATABASE db1;
USE             db1;

CREATE TABLE `table_1` (
  `id`   INT  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` TEXT NOT NULL,
  `YYYY` TEXT NOT NULL,
  `ZZZZ` TEXT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

```
CREATE DATABASE db2;
USE             db2;

CREATE TABLE `table_1` (
  `id`   INT  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` TEXT NOT NULL,
  `YYYY` TEXT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Comment: Great explanation of the process.  Thank you.